# C# Unable to return an error message from a method

Tags: c#

I'm still fairly new to the C# language and started learning more about methods this week.  I am having an issue getting my error messages to display on my form. Any assistance to point me in the right direction and to understand what I am missing will be GREATLY appreciated.  After several hours I managed to get public int calcAge(int aGE) to work, however, private void ErrorReturns(string errorStringReturn) has been causing me a royal headache.

```
    private void executeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textBox = nameTextBox.Text;
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime futurePicker = futureDateTimePicker.Value;
        int AGE = 0;
        string errorString = null;

        
        int ageCalculation = calcAge(AGE);
        ErrorReturns(errorString);

        responseLabel.Text = "Hello " + textBox + "! You will be " + ageCalculation + " on " + futurePicker.ToShortDateString() + '\n' + "A date that is " + (futurePicker - today).Days + " days from now";
    }

    public int calcAge(int aGE)
    {
        DateTime birthdatePicker = birthDateTimePicker.Value;
        DateTime futurePicker = futureDateTimePicker.Value;

        aGE = futurePicker.Year - birthdatePicker.Year;

        if (futurePicker < birthdatePicker.AddYears(aGE))
        {
            aGE--; // Decrement years if the Day has not passed yet.
        }
        return aGE;
    }
    private void ErrorReturns(string errorStringReturn)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime birthdatePicker = birthDateTimePicker.Value;
        DateTime futurePicker = futureDateTimePicker.Value;

        if (futurePicker < today)
        {
            responseLabel.Text = "ERROR -- DATE MUST BE IN THE FUTURE -- Please select a date in the future.";
        }
        else if (birthdatePicker > today)
        {
            responseLabel.Text = "ERROR -- DATE MUST BE IN THE PAST -- Please select a date in the past.";
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: What does `errorString` ? It is not used in the code provided...

Comment: Why are you passing the errorStringReturn parameter to ErrorReturns?  It doesn't appear to be used at all.

Comment: Your Button click code is always updating the label so you will never see the error message.  Have ErrorReturns return a string and check that, or have ErrorReturns raise an exception and handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does errorString ? It is not used in the code provided...

Else the problem is that you always set the label text with:

```
responseLabel.Text = "Hello " + textBox + "! You will be " + ageCalculation + " on " + futurePicker.ToShortDateString() + '\n' + "A date that is " + (futurePicker - today).Days + " days from now";
```

Even if you set it before using the `ErrorReturns` method.

You can do that:

```
private bool CheckDate()
{
  DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
  DateTime birthdatePicker = birthDateTimePicker.Value;
  DateTime futurePicker = futureDateTimePicker.Value;

  if ( futurePicker < today )
  {
    responseLabel.Text = "ERROR -- DATE MUST BE IN THE FUTURE -- Please select a date in the future.";
    return false;
  }
  else 
  if ( birthdatePicker > today )
  {
    responseLabel.Text = "ERROR -- DATE MUST BE IN THE PAST -- Please select a date in the past.";
    return false;
  }
  else
    return true;
}
```

And now you can write:

```
private void executeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string textBox = nameTextBox.Text;
  DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
  DateTime futurePicker = futureDateTimePicker.Value;
  int AGE = 0;
  string errorString = null;

  int ageCalculation = calcAge(AGE);

  if ( CheckDate() )
    responseLabel.Text = "Hello " + textBox + "! You will be " + ageCalculation + " on " + futurePicker.ToShortDateString() + '\n' + "A date that is " + ( futurePicker - today ).Days + " days from now";
}
```

I have not checked the logic of what you do, here it only solve the display.

To have a better UX you should not use the same label, but another thing, another label/image in red, or a message box, for example, so the user is better advised of what's happend.

Comment: errorString was me trying trail and error to figure the issue out myself.  My class this semester has been a, teach your self class. Almost nothing from this project was covered and we were told to google most of the required code.  What you provided is perfect and something I would have never thought of.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what other colleagues already mentioned regarding passing the "errorStringReturn" as null (which does not make any sense), are you sure that any of the conditionals above are reached?
Please, make a test and change the following to "futurePicker", just to see if you are able to return the error to the responseLabel.

```
    else if (futurePicker  > today)
    {
        responseLabel.Text = "ERROR -- DATE MUST BE IN THE PAST -- Please select a date in the past.";
    }
```

Another question, does the responseLabel shows the message "Hello.." in the beginning?

Comment: That was me just trying trial and error.  I just didn't remove it before posting.  To your other question yes it does show Hello.